# Cannot project <mat-error>s into a custom component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 8 app that is using Angular Material. I am trying to create a reusable form component that implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. It contains its own form that has two controls, like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ nameLabel }}</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      formControlName="name"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (blur)="onTouched()"/>
    <ng-content select="[name-errors]"></ng-content>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ dateLabel }}</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="picker"
      formControlName="plannedEnd"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    <ng-content select="[date-errors]"></ng-content>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

and its TypeScript:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, forwardRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormComponent, FormModel } from '@turntown/shared';

import * as moment from 'moment';
import { CreateScheduleReport } from '@turntown/cost-control/set-up/shared';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

@Component({
  selector: 'cc-name-and-date',
  templateUrl: './name-and-date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-and-date.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => NameAndDateComponent),
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class NameAndDateComponent implements OnInit, FormComponent, ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {

  @Input() nameLabel: string;
  @Input() dateLabel: string;
  private readonly unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  disabled;
  form;
  onChange = (value: CreateScheduleReport) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(newValue: CreateScheduleReport): void {
    this.form.setValue(newValue);
    this.onChange(newValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  constructor(protected formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.initForm();
    this.onChange(this.form.value);

    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
    ).subscribe(newFormValue => {
      this.onChange(newFormValue);
      this.onTouched();
    });
  }

  hasError(formControlName: string, error: string): boolean {
    MomentDateAdapter
    return this.form.get(formControlName).hasError(error) && this.form.get(formControlName).touched;
  }

  initForm(): FormGroup {
    const form: FormModel<CreateScheduleReport> = {
      name: [''],
      plannedEnd: [moment()],
    };
    return this.formBuilder.group(form);
  }

  submitForm(event: any): void {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

I am using this component like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <section class="first-reporting-period-details">
    <mat-card>
      <h1>First reporting period details</h1>
      <h3 tt-small>Planned end date of period</h3>

      <cc-name-and-date
        nameLabel="Period Name"
        dateLabel="Period End Date"
        formControlName="period">
        <ng-container name-errors>
          <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('period', 'invalidPeriodName')">
            This is mandatory
          </mat-error>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container date-errors>
          <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('period', 'invalidPeriodDate')">
            The first reporting period end date must be today or later
          </mat-error>
        </ng-container>
      </cc-name-and-date>
    </mat-card>
  </section>

  <section class="first-stage-details">
    <mat-card>
      <h1>First stage details</h1>
      <h3 tt-small>Planned end date of stage</h3>
      <cc-name-and-date
        nameLabel="Stage Name"
        dateLabel="Stage End Date"
        formControlName="stage">
        <ng-container name-errors>
          <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('stage', 'invalidStageName')">
            This is mandatory
          </mat-error>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container date-errors>
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('invalidStageDate')">
            The first stage end date must be the same as the first reporting period end date or later
          </mat-error>
        </ng-container>
      </cc-name-and-date>
    </mat-card>
  </section>

</form>
```

As you can see, I am attempting to perform the validation logic in the container component, and am attempting to use content projection to pass in the errors to the child component.

All of this logic works, but unfortunately, the errors projected do not render properly in the browser. When a validation error occurs, the message renders *inside* the form control, like this:

[image: Screenshot of validation errors]

This is obviously not ideal, and not acceptable to my boss! I would have thought that this problem would have been solved since it seems like a simple enough pattern, but I can't find any example on the www with this pattern working.

I have checked the DOM in Chrome and it appears that the `<mat-error>`s are in a different place when they are projected, but I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a 2yr old known bug.
there's an open issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411) for it.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @Stavm I don't think that's the same issue with this one. I'm a beginner with angular, but it could be that the resolution of `ng-content` happens after the population of `mat-form-field` elements?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to put the `<ng-container>` inside the `<mat-error>`?
I tried to make a component for custom error and use it like this

```
<mat-error>
   <form-error [control]="formGroup.controls.type" field="Name"></form-error>
</mat-error>
```